# htaccess rewrite doesn't work on 2nd level rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following lines in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                  seo.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^seo/site:(.*)$         seo.php?p=seo&domain=/$1&status=seo [QSA]
RewriteRule ^seo/(.*)$              seo.php?p=seo&domain=/$1&status=seo [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/page:(.*)$       seo.php?p=admin&page=/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^webagent/page:(.*)$    seo.php?p=webagent&page=/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^setlang:(.*)$          seo.php?setlang=/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/setlang:(.*)$     seo.php?p=/$1&setlang=/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that only first Rule works normal. it takes pages from currently defined folder in php
When i try to open

> seo/domain.com

it doesn't work but when i open

> seo.php?p=seo&domain=domain.com&status=seo

works very well.

Where i go wrong with this .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^seo/site:(.*)$         seo.php?p=seo&domain=/$1&status=seo [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^seo/(.*)$              seo.php?p=seo&domain=/$1&status=seo [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/page:(.*)$       seo.php?p=admin&page=/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^webagent/page:(.*)$    seo.php?p=webagent&page=/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^setlang:(.*)$          seo.php?setlang=/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/setlang:(.*)$     seo.php?p=/$1&setlang=/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                  seo.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```